# Using merge sort for strings with numbers (ruby)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am having some trouble with using merge sort for a particular type of inputs. The goal is to sort an array of strings with numbers like this:

```
["0 ab", "6 cd", "0 ef", "6 gh", "4 ij", "0 ab", "6 cd", "0 ef", "6 gh", "0 ij", "4 that", "3 be", "0 to", "1 be", "5 question", "1 or", "2 not", "4 is", "2 to", "4 the"]
```

... that should return the sorted array but without the numbers and in the order they appeared :

```
# => ["ab", "ef", "ab", "ef", "ij", "to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be", "ij", "that", "is", "the", "question", "cd", "gh", "cd", "gh"]
```

I am having trouble returning the sorted array without the numbers as I am using the numbers to sort the array.

Up until now, what I am having is this:

```
["0 ab", "0 ef", "0 ab", "0 ef", "0 ij", "0 to", "1 be", "1 or", "2 not", "2 to", "3 be", "4 ij", "4 that", "4 is", "4 the", "5 question", "6 cd", "6 gh", "6 cd", "6 gh"].
```

What I have tried: 
I tried to remove the numbers and space using regex but it doesn't work because it's a recursion. It will then take whatever element without a number and compare it to the other ones. Which will not respect the order of sorting.

My code is :

```
def full_merge_sort(array)
  # write your code here
  if(array.length <= 1 )
    return array
  end 

  med = (array.length / 2).floor
  left = full_merge_sort(array.slice(0, med))
  right = full_merge_sort(array.slice(med, array.length))

 merged = merge_sort(left, right)


  return merged

end 





def merge_sort(array1, array2)
  # write your code here
  i = 0; 
  j = 0; 
  sorted_arr = []
  while(i < array1.length && j < array2.length)
  numArr1 = array1[i].gsub(/\D+/, "").to_i
  numArr2 = array2[j].gsub(/\D+/, "").to_i
  if(numArr1 <= numArr2 )
    sorted_arr << array1[i]
    i+= 1 

  else
    sorted_arr << array2[j]
    j += 1
  end 
end

while(i < array1.length)
  sorted_arr << array1[i]
  i += 1
end 


while(j < array2.length)
  sorted_arr << array2[j]
  j += 1
end 


sorted_arr

end
```

Comment: In Ruby `;` is used to separate multiple statements on the same line, and it's usually used sparingly. There's no need to put it at the end of any given line, it serves no purpose there.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Hint: Don't remove the number from the original string, instead *transform* the original values into tuples (pairs, as contained in individual arrays) and pass those through to whatever sorting function you need. The way this works without all your custom code is `array.sort_by { |v| v.split(' ').tap { |a| a[0] = a[0].to_i } }`

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I don't really understand the goal of tuples. Will it then return the elements without the numbers? Is there any other way to have the expected result? Thanks

Comment: What I mean is to split this into an intermediate form, sort it, and then convert that into the final form.

Comment: If I do array.sort_by( |v| v.split(' ').tap{ |a| a[0] = a[0].to_i}}, I am getting this:  
=> ["0 ab", "0 ab", "0 ef", "0 ef", "0 ij", "0 to", "1 be", "1 or", "2 not", "2 to", "3 be", "4 ij", "4 is", "4 that", "4 the", "5 question", "6 cd", "6 cd", "6 gh", "6 gh"]  However, ths is not the desired result. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just sorting and not to make a sort method per-se:

```
array.map do |v|
  # Split the values into two parts...
  v.split(' ').tap do |a|
    a[0] = a[0].to_i # ...and convert the first of each pair to an integer
  end
end.sort_by do |v|
  v[0] # sort by the first entry in each pair...
end.map(&:last) # ...then extract just the second value in each.
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the desired result. But I still don't see how I could implement this in the merge sort. Any directions?

Comment: The merge sort has some kind of sort value, so think of it that way with the split values. Use that in the comparator. `merge_sort(array.map { ... })`